# Error in authorization process

Tags: google-bigquery

We're getting following error from Google bigquery while inserts:

** No OAuth2 credentials found, beginning authorization process **

```
== Platform ==
  CPython:2.7.5:Windows-2008ServerR2-6.1.7601-SP1
== bq version ==
  v2.0.17
== Command line ==
  ['C:\\LogsReceiverService\\bq-script.py', 'load', '--nosync', '--credential_file=C:\\LogsReceiverService\\.bigquery.v2.token', '--source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON', '--project_id=playscape-proj', '--max_bad_records=99999', 'PROD_DATASET.CLIENT_LOGS_20160424', 'D:\\GameConsoleLogs\\Logs_BigQuery\\GameConsoleClientLog.log.1.gz']
== UTC timestamp ==
  2016-04-24 13:32:53
== Error trace ==
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\bq.py", line 783, in RunSafely
    return_value = self.RunWithArgs(*args, **kwds)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\bq.py", line 999, in RunWithArgs
    client = Client.Get()
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\bq.py", line 604, in Get
    cls.client = Client.Create()
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\bq.py", line 584, in Create
    credentials = _GetCredentialsFromFlags()
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\bq.py", line 390, in _GetCredentialsFromFlags
    credentials = credentials_getter(storage)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\bq.py", line 330, in _GetCredentialsFromOAuthFlow
    credentials = oauth2client.tools.run(flow, storage)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\oauth2client\util.py", line 132, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\oauth2client\old_run.py", line 149, in run
    code = raw_input('Enter verification code: ').strip()
========================================
```

The message also include a link with a token key, but we're not sure what we should do with it.

Can you please help? thanks

Answer (score 0):

When running bq (or any gcloud operation), the client needs to have OAuth credentials for the user running the operation. Usually these clients ask for credentials on first use, but it sounds like that isn't happening in your case. (Or maybe the credentials file is corrupt?)

To remove the bq client's copy of the credentials file, run `bq init --delete_credentials`.

To attempt to re-authenticate, use `bq init`. Note that if you are using the gcloud client to talk to other Google services, `bq.py` prefers those credentials, so you may need to run `gcloud auth login --enable-gdrive-access` after deleting the local BigQuery credentials. (The `--enable-grdive-access` is optional, but it will allow the new BigQuery federated query feature over Google Sheets. You may or may not require this feature.)

Another option for credentials: if you are going to run these operations as scripts without human intervention, you can use Service Account Credentials so these operations are done as another identity rather than with your personal credentials. There are two options here depending on where you are going to run your scripts:

- You can create a service account in your project and download the credentials, then use the `--service_account`, `--service_account_private_key_file`, and `--service_account_private_key_password` flags to run the operations as the service account rather than with your personal identity.
- If you are running `bq` inside a GCE instance, you can specify the single flag `--user_gce_service_account` and the bq client will load credentials from the GCE container.

Comment: When I run `bq init --delete_credentials`  I get this error message 'The "init" command is no longer needed with the Cloud SDK.'

Comment: @AnthonyKong You can now use `gcloud auth application-default` instead to login to the default group with your personal gmail account.